# How can I black out text in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I'd like to black out specific text from a document so that the words are fully concealed. I know how to put a line through the text, but not how to adjust the size of that line so that the text under it doesn't appear at all.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the text and pick its colour as black *not* automatic. Select the highlight tool, and pick black as well, and apply a highlight.

Of course, this still means its possible to read with copying it and pasting it to plain text.

Comment: Great, thank you! So the only way to 'strike it out' so the text wouldn't still be part of the document would be to print to a pdf or image and actually block out the text?

Comment: Printing to image might work there. Or, not actually have the text there

Comment: Please note that even if you can't copy/paste text, the text is still in the document itself and can be extracted fairly easily, as some secret service found several years ago. They published declassified documents with blacked out text in PS and/or PDF. In PS at least, it's a matter of minutes to remove all black bars and get the original text. To hide text from a document securely, don't put it in in the first place.

Comment: Yup - even have a link to that in my comment to sleske's answer, and my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can set text color and background (highlighting) color to black, as explained in Journeyman Geek's answer - but note that the text will still be there, and readable by copy/paste or by directly inspecting the file.

To actually remove the text, replace it with spaces, *then* select the emtpy space and set background to black.

I just tested this with a simple text file in Writer (LibreOffice 3.4.3). If you delete the text, it is indeed gone, even from the ODT file.

Comment: Yes, i considered that -  but decided thats not what he wanted based off the question. I mean, if [even the US government does it that way...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanitization_(classified_information)#Computer_media_and_files)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Well, you have a point. I added my answer after reading evan's comment to your answer, which looks like OP really wants the text gone.

Comment: upvoted anyway, cause it was commonsensical, and have should have been in my answer anyway ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Well, thinking about it, both solutions may make sense. If the document is meant for printing out, the author might want to keep the original text, in case it is needed again later. And thanks for the upvote :-).

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy way to Black out either a word or sentence is as follows.

select a shape > rectangle > select and draw over text > right click box select area > fill with Black....   Job done.